Where does it say in "God of War III" that Olympus has the underworld transform souls into the monsters that you've been fighting?
For those of you who are not familiar with the series, God of War is the series where the demigod Kratos kills Ares, becomes the God of War, and then declares war on the Olympians. God of War III is the game where Kratos leads the Titans to attack Mount Olympus. Spoiler warning: everybody onscreen dies, except for Athena (by virtue of being a ghost) and Kratos (because of his curse).
What makes the third game fascinating is that almost none of the characters are good guys. In fact, at least one fan has found themselves rooting for the Olympians instead of Kratos, the protagonist.
That being said, the Moral Event Horizon page on TVTropes.org essentially says that instead of sending ordinary souls to the Asphodel Fields, the underworld transforms them into the very monsters that Kratos has been fighting throughout the series. In other words, the Olympians crossed the line where they lose any hope of redemption.
Now, here is the problem. I have watched at least one playthrough of God of War III on YouTube, but I have not seen this mentioned. Is it somewhere in the game, or in the manual?
This must be an obscure detail, because I hardly ever see fans bring it up.

Of course, I am not sure if Kratos was aware of the Olympians creating monsters out of the souls of deceased people, but considering how he acted in God of War III, I get the feeling that he wouldn't have cared at the time.
